# What type of glue should I use to paste a vinyl sheet to a wall?

Tags: adhesive

I have a vinyl banner(width: 6'; height: 8'), which needs to be pasted on the wall. I want to know if there's any glue which can act as adhesive between a vinyl sheet and a painted wall.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think you or someone else will ever want to remove this banner? If so, you should consider wallpaper paste

Comment: Yeah, may after an year or two, we might want to remove. In that case, will wallpaper paste be strong enough to hold on to a painted wall & a vinyl sheet ?

Comment: Wallpaper paste is designed to hold indefinitely but allow removal with the right technique.  Check for a product which is suitable with vinyl wall covering. If you use some types of powerful adhesive, you will never be able to remove the vinyl banner or adhesive residue without destroying the wall. And some adhesives have a strong and persistent odor. Wallpaper paste doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.  It comes in 11oz and 30 oz. cartridge tubes, as well as, 1 gal. and 4 gal. containers under the search heading "vinyl adhesive".

I've used it on shower surrounds, rolled vinyl flooring, and a faux leather vinyl wall covering.

I find the most important consideration, during application, is to spread the adhesive well, for even coverage, to avoid "high spots" that may be evident afterward.  A V-notch 3/16" x 5/32" cove base adhesive spreader works best but for large areas a 1/4" (or smaller) square notch trowel will do.

[Edit: oh, and a regular baking rolling pin or a similar type of roller on a pole will help ensure the finishing material is pressed into the adhesive.]

[2nd edit: when rolling, start in the center and work toward the edges to prevent air bubbles...as one would to hang wallpaper.]